# Can I give a hotel address for my permesso di soggiorno?

Tags: resident-permit, italy

I'm going to stay for 5 months in Italy due to work. I already got my work visa at the embassy and I know that I must fill the documents to get a permesso di soggiorno within 8 days of my arrival.

I know that I need to inform an address during the interview (at the questura) for the permesso and I would like to know if I can provide them a hotel address. I would prefer to live in the hotel than renting a place.

Answer (score 1):

If that is where you are residing, that should cause no problem.

The goal of giving a residence is that they know where they can get in contact with you if needed.